# Getting content/excerpt from zend lucene search result

Tags: php, lucene, zend-lucene

Im implementing zend-lucene search on my site, and I have indexing going well, and I can search.

But the results just come back with the records that have a hit in order of score without the content (other than extra fields).

Id like to be able to show where in the content the match was. Is this possible?

I know that the content is index but not stored for space reasons. So do I have to mix this with a SQL query if I want to return back a excerpt?

Also... Is it possible to see where the match was made? Like title vs author vs content?

Answer (score 0):

The Zend Lucene alone does not support it. I solved it by storing the search content as text and using following function from this threar to display the excerpt:
[How to generate excerpt with most searched words in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436582/how-to-generate-excerpt-with-most-searched-words-in-php/32252895#32252895)